# Hidden Form Headers while inspecting page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I was trying to log into roll20.com using `requests` but I wasn't able to find the Form Headers with the login info in the DevTools while inspecting the webpage. Is it possible that those are hidden to prevent people like me from doing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I can conclude, that you can login via requests using code below (at least it works on **roll20.net**):

```
import requests
import base64
import re

loginData = {
    'email':'mymail@mail.com',
    'password':'password'}

# basic headers for request
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Referer':'https://app.roll20.net/login'}

# send request for creating a session
resp1 = requests.post(
    url='https://app.roll20.net/v2/sessions/create', 
    data=loginData,
    headers=headers)


# parse cookie from response header
# we need it to authorizate successfully
cookie = resp1.headers['set-cookie']
cookie = re.search(r'(rack.session=([^;]+))', cookie).group()
headers['Cookie'] = cookie

print(resp1.status_code)
print(resp1.headers)
print('\n\n')

# update header 'Referer'
headers['Referer']='https://app.roll20.net/login'

# requesting home page of the site
resp2 = requests.get(
    url='https://app.roll20.net/home', 
    headers=headers)

print(resp2.status_code)
print(resp1.headers)
print('\n\n\n')

# saving last response body as file to check it was ok
with open('index.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.writelines(resp2.text)
```

All you need - provide your own login/password in **loginData** dictionary.
After that you can check file *index.html*, there you can find authorization was successful.

[Final result in index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEoHq.jpg)

Can't find any useful of this anyway, it's up to you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, but I was more interested in finding a method to do this sort of thing on any website. I thought that going to the devtools and finding the login form will provide me with the necessary payload info for a login on any site, but I either didn't find it or it is being hidden from me on purpose. Anyway: the reason I want this is so I can create character sheets for mobs and NPCs using my own, customizeable NPC, randomiser (once it is finished). It would make tracking and rolling for mobs way more transparent than tracking stuff in notepad during a session.

Comment: @J.Doe When you are on https://app.roll20.net/login and sending your login/password (by pressing "Login" button), there happens almost immediately redirection, but if you stop it from reloading page, you will see there are one POST request, which is send not by you, but with JS. 
I just fetch session create link from the request and it was https://app.roll20.net/v2/sessions/create
After session was created, it is now linked with session cookie, which i retrieve from first response, and you can  enter https://app.roll20.net/home as if you do usual login using browser.

Comment: how do I stop a the page from refreshing? Sorry, you seem to know a lot of magic I am oblivious to.

Comment: @J.Doe you should press "Login" button. When the page start to reload you stop it. In Firefox it's enough to press "Esc" button to stop reloading page. BTW, it's important to hold DevTools open during all this.
Also I think it's possible to use wireshark and monitor traffic, but it's more complicated as for me.